# Элемент становится блоком?

Tags: html, бэм

на одном из репозиториев нашел код

```
<div class="news">
    <h3 class="news__title">Вчерашние новости</h3>
    <ul class="news__list">
        <!-- к классу элемента добавляем класс блока,
             чтобы создать новое пространство имён -->
        <li class="news__item item-news">
            <h4 class="item-news__title">Соревнования среди воблы по конькобежному спорту</h4>
```

интересуют конкретно действия после закомментированного текста, в результате которого **элемент** с классом `.news__item` становится **блоком** `.item-news`. это законно вообще? или это и есть микс, который автор называет как "новое пространство имён"?

Comment: По бэм должно быть news__item-news

Comment: Нельзя, чтобы элемент становился блоком и наоборот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, один DOM-узел может быть одновременно и элементом и блоком, это совершенно нормально и называется [микс](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81). Вот пример из официальной документации (по ссылке):

```
<!-- Блок `header` -->
<div class="header">
    <!-- К блоку `search-form` примиксован элемент `search-form` блока `header`-->
    <div class="search-form header__search-form"></div>
</div>
```

В примере выше преимущество такого подхода заключается в том, что позиционирование внутреннего DOM-узла (который одновременно и элемент и блок) может быть задано в стилях элемента (`.header__search-form`), а собственные стили могут быть написаны в блоке (`.search-form`).

---

В вашем примере имеются два блока:

- Блок `news`
- Блок `item-news`

И элементы:

- Элементы блока `news`:

  - `news__title`
  - `news__list`
  - `news__item`
- Элементы блока `item-news`:

  - `item-news__title`

DOM-узел после закомментированного текста является одновременно блоком `item-news` и элементом (`news__item`) блока `news`

Comment: следовательно, если в вашем примере внутри <div class="search-form header__search-form"></div> будет input, то у него будет класс .search-form__input?

Comment: @urpride например `.search-form__input`, да. Вместо `input` можно, конечно, и какое-нибудь другое имя дать. Также необязательно все DOM-узлы превращать в блоки/элементы

Comment: в общем для позиционирования и геометрии используется микс или создается родительский блок, верно?

Comment: @urpride для позиции блока внутри другого блока используется микс, но для позиции элементов одного блока относительно друг друга совсем необязательно создавать микс или ещё один блок

Comment: огромное спасибо.)